# Move Event Log in Windows 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log, eventviewer

Ultimately I'm trying to have security logs written to a remote storage,

```
\\Server-Name\Drive-Letter\File_Name.evtx
```

For testing I'm trying to move the default log path from `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx` to `C:\Security.evtx` . 
This however is failing; no errors in logs.

I double checked the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Security` and the `File` does point to `C:\Security.evtx` however logs are still written in the default `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx`. I double checked and no group policy is in place for this.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I'm aware of `wevtutil` however I'd like to accomplish this using Event Viewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.  Whatever the problem is, the solution is not to relocate the event logs to a network location.  You can copy them to a network location, use [event forwarding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890(v=ws.11).aspx) to forward the logs to another computer, or relocate the logs to another *local* drive, but you can't move them to a network location.

Windows expects and requires the event logging service to be available before it initializes the network stack, so your idea is a non-starter.

Comment: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890(v=ws.11).aspx